# jQuery returns the same opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opacity

I am trying to use simple animation with `opacity` css property:

```
$('#testAnimation').click(function (event) {
    if ($(this).css('opacity') == 0) {
        $('#animationTarget').animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
    } else {
        $('#animationTarget').animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow');
    }
});
```

The first time, element is successfully hidden. But when I click button second time, `$(this).css('opacity')` returns value `"1"`.

Debugging in browser clearly says that `opacity` is `0`.

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: if you're using a 0 opacity why don't you use `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`?

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni because I am newcomer to jquery universe, I simply ded not reach that documentation section :) Thank you for suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking the `opacity` of `this` and changing the one of the `#animationTarget`.

This should do it:

```
$('#testAnimation').click(function (event) {
  if ($('#animationTarget').css('opacity') == 0) {
    $('#animationTarget').animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
  } else {
    $('#animationTarget').animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this was my fault.

For anyone who faces similar issue, be sure that you are checking property of the desired element:

```
if ($(this).css('opacity') == 0)
```

Should be replaced with:

```
if ($('#animationTarget').css('opacity') == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` to achieve what you are doing.
Less code to write. have a look at the `:visible` part as I don't remember if it is the correct syntax!

```
$('#testAnimation').click(function (event) {
  if ($(this).is(':visible') {
      $(this).fadeOut();
  } else {
      $(this).fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Comment: I found very useful facade method to achieve the same result: http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

Answer (score 0):

Checking for `$(this)` within your click event handler you will refer to the element `$('#testAnimation')`

Instead you should check for `$('#animationTarget')` and also you can refactor your code like this:

```
$('#testAnimation').on('click', function (event) {
    var $animationTarget = $('#animationTarget'),
        opacity = $animationTarget.css('opacity') == 0 ? 1 : 0;     
    $animationTarget.animate({opacity: opacity}, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: If I am not mistaking: `$('#animationTarget').css('opacity') === 0` will always return `false` because of type checking. Am I wrong? And what is the purpose of setting opacity to `2`?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov Thanks for the comment!